# How to create an Excel formula that is dependant on cell color

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a row of cells colored green containing actual payments and yellow cells containing the amount intended to pay. In column A I have the total currently owed for a given invoice. What I need is to be able to subtract the contents of any cell colored green from the invoice amount in column A.

Answer (score 1):

Color is not data.

If you already have conditional formatting in place, use logic along the same lines to create the sum.

Comment: To clarify, the cell color is defined by the user and NOT by conditional formatting. The cell color of yellow is defined by the user to show which amounts the user intends to pay. Once the amount is paid by the user, the user turns the cell color to green. So what is required is to subtract the green cell amounts in a given row from the amount in column A. Incidentally, I know that color is not data but how do I do this?

Comment: so, why did you tag with "conditional-formatting"? Again, color is not data. It's a bad habit to color cells to convey specific meaning. Use real data like text or numbers to flag a status for a cell. Then it's easy to sum with Sumif or similar functions.

Comment: Apologies as I am new to this forum. The "conditional-formatting" tag has been removed. I also appreciate your comment about using cell color to convey specific meaning as a bad habit. However, I have been given this spreadsheet by a user and I need to provide a solution. Is there one (in spite of it being a bad habit)?

Comment: The only way to do that (as per your requirement) is via VBA. There isn't any formula based solution ... unless you can provide any type of condition or mapping for the colored cells.